# E447: Can't find file "iostream" in path

Tags: c++, vim, iostream

I'm currently using Vim. To open iostream I go over it with cursor and type in `g` `f`. After that in the bottom of the screen I get this message: `E447: Can't find file "iostream" in path`. (All of my files .cpp files work perfectly fine)

Comment: Obviously, it does not know the proper path to `iostream`. It isn't under the standard `/usr/include`, but instead under something similar to `/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what could've caused that

Comment: I don't think anything caused it. I think the `.cpp` files you are opening are likely in the current working directory, or within a defined set of paths. I suspect the mapping for `g` `f` simply does not include the path to the C++ header files (or you updated C++ versions and vim hasn't updated yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gf` looks up the filename under the cursor in the directories specified in the `path` option. By default (on unix systems), the `path` option is set to `.,/usr/include,,`. This default is not sufficient to find C++ standard library headers directly.

In order to make `gf` find the C++ standard library headers, you can add the `/usr/include/c++/<version>/` directory to  `path`, e.g. like so:

```
:set path=.,/usr/include,,/usr/include/c++/*/
```